# Measure the time required for an image to show on the screen?

Tags: java, image, testing, paint

I would like to measure the time it takes for an image to appear on-screen in Java.

I can override the `paint()` method and see how long that method takes to execute, but I am not sure if the image is on the screen at the end of that method. Basically, I want to fill these requirements:

- Time to show an image on-screen is consistent to within a few milliseconds
- I can determine the time it takes to show an image

  [Lower priority] Images show as quickly as possible

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to hook into the event-dispatch thread and measure the time it takes for it to carry out the repaint event induced by the "show this image" update. May be a better way though.

Answer (score 0):

The [drawImage()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage(java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver)) method of Graphics has an ImageObserver parameter which looks like it is called when the image has finished drawing. I've never used it, but it might be of some help.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure if you can call it from Java, but the Firebug Firefox extension shows download times for all the components of a page including images. If nothing else, you could use it as a benchmark to compare your Java solution against as you work on it.